# Spring Boot. A Bean Depends on a Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Below I have a `customUserDetailsService` property, and a `tokenAuthenticationService` property. I need to pass `customUserDetailsService` into `tokenAuthenticationService` but `tokenAuthenticationService` is a `@Bean` file and  `customUserDetailsService` is a `@Service` which means that `tokenAuthenticationService` gets called first with parameter for `UserDetailsService` as `null` for the `UserDetailsService` parameter. I need to either delay the initiation of `tokenAuthenticationService` as a Bean or Turn `tokenAuthenticationService` into a service as well and some how pass those parameters as a constructor. How do I go about doing this ?

```
  package app.config;

    import app.repo.User.CustomUserDetailsService;
    import app.security.*;
    import app.security.filters.StatelessAuthenticationFilter;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    @Order(2)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static PasswordEncoder encoder;

        @Autowired
        private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

        public WebSecurityConfig() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.httpBasic();
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
            http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
            http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
            http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
            tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", customUserDetailsService);
            return tokenAuthenticationService;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you post a stacktrace? Ordinarily Spring would finish autowiring the configuration class before invoking its factory methods, but cyclic dependencies (or dependencies of Bean(Factory)PostProcessors) may prevent that.

Comment: Where `TokenAuthenticationService` is coming from? Can you add constructor which just takes one argument and Autowire userDetailService?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the userDetailsService as direct dependency of the TokenAuthenticationService like this:

```
@Bean
public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", userDetailsService);
    return tokenAuthenticationService;
}
```

That way, Spring will make sure, that the UserDetailsService is instantiated and injected when the TokenAuthenticationService is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try annotating tokenAuthenticationService() with [@Lazy](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html). Though even if that worked its a bit unpredictable, and future modifications to this or related beans may leave you wondering on why it stopped working.

Best to declare `TokenAuthenticationService` as `@Service` & inject `UserDetailsService` in it.

As a side note its better to not mix @Configuration with application code to avoid these kind of issues.

**Update** - I don't think @Lazy is going to work here. Since you are relying on @Bean being invoked in the middle of @Autowired beans being processed.

In order for your code to work the `@Autowired` customUserDetailsService should be set first, then `@Bean` method called and then `@Autowired` tokenAuthenticationService should be set.